# object disposed exception on DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework, dispose

I have a DataGrid that for some reason I have to declare as a global. everything seems to be working fine at first use. But when I go back to the form for another try, an object disposed exception is called. Is there anyway for me to prevent this? like dispose the public datagrid or something? Here is a sample of my code:

```
public static DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
public myForm()  
{
InitializeComponent();
dataGrid.Location = pt;
dataGrid.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
dataGrid.Font.Size = 9;
dataGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Azure;
dataGrid.GridLineColor = Color.Black;
dataGrid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dataGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 60;
this.Controls.Add(dataGrid);
dataGrid.Height = 524;
dataGrid.Width = 468;
dataGrid.CurrentCellChanged += new
EventHandler(dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged);
}
```

Comment: Provide more details of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Where are you get the exception?

Comment: The exception occurs on dataGrid.Location = pt.
This is happening if I use the form for the 2nd time.

Comment: That is because , your form will dispose anything in its component when the form is disposed , since you are adding it to this.controls list , you may not be able to use it after the form is disposed. my suggestion .. don't use static datagrid

Answer (score 1):

A `Form` (or indeed any `Control`) disposes its child controls when it is disposed.  So what you're seeing is normal.

To achieve what you want, you'd need to remove the DataGrid from the Form's Controls collection before it is disposed.

**UPDATE**

As @ctacke says in comments, there are almost certainly alternatives that will avoid your needing to make the `DataGrid` static, but without more detail it's difficult to make a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what made me overcome this error was to just recreate the dataGrid every initialization in the form. Im not sure if this is safe though. So instead of public static DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid(); I just put public static DataGrid dataGrid; and inside Initialization I put dataGrid = new DataGrid();

Comment: @jeraldov - that will work, of course, but it does seem strange to want to make your DataGrid static ("... for some reason I have to declare as a global").

Comment: its because i have a class that checks my datagrid's contents and change the row color.

Comment: Then you should pass the DataGrid instance to that class, not have it as a "global".

Comment: ...or subclass the DataGrid to add your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have a static control, at least provide a wrapper for it so that you can catch and handle your issues.

Consider modifying your code to being something like below. Once you have your bugs ironed out, you can eliminate any of the stuff you don't really need.

```
private static DataGrid dataGrid;
private static myForm myInstance;

public myForm()  
{
  InitializeComponent();
  myInstance = this; // set 'myInstance' before DataGrid1 stuff
  DataGrid1.Height = 524;
  DataGrid1.Width = 468;
  DataGrid1.CurrentCellChanged += new EventHandler(dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged);
}

public static DataGrid DataGrid1 {
  get {
    try {
      if ((myInstance == null) || myInstance.IsDisposed) {
        throw new Exception("myForm is already disposed. No controls available.");
      }
      if ((dataGrid == null) || dataGrid.IsDisposed) {
        dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Location = pt;
        dataGrid.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
        dataGrid.Font.Size = 9;
        dataGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Azure;
        dataGrid.GridLineColor = Color.Black;
        dataGrid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 60;
        this.Controls.Add(dataGrid);
      }
    } catch (Exception err) {
      Console.WriteLine(err); // put a breakpoint HERE
    }
    return dataGrid;
  }
  set {
    try {
      if ((myInstance == null) || myInstance.IsDisposed) {
        throw new Exception("myForm is already disposed. No controls available.");
      }
      if ((dataGrid == null) || dataGrid.IsDisposed) {
        dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Location = pt;
        dataGrid.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
        dataGrid.Font.Size = 9;
        dataGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Azure;
        dataGrid.GridLineColor = Color.Black;
        dataGrid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 60;
        this.Controls.Add(dataGrid);
      }
    } catch (Exception err) {
      Console.WriteLine(err); // put a breakpoint HERE
    }
    dataGrid = value;
  }
}
```

Finally, make sure your `dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged` event handler (and everything else in your program) references this public `DataGrid1` object, and not the `dataGrid` - or you'll find yourself having those same errors all over again.